# Referencing to non-float objects without a caption

Tags: cross-referencing

In my thesis I have defined Boxes.  In these boxes I give additional background information or definitions that are too detailed for my main text. These environments are not floats, and they do not have a caption. The box number is  displayed and defined in the object itself. I cannot put the boxes into a float because they no longer work when I do.

I would like to refer to the boxes in the text. Using `\label{}` and `\ref{}` does not work as it, obviously, gives the section number. I only have a limited number of boxes and only in the introduction, so I would be fine with a solution to number them manually. But I would like to keep the clickable links in the pdf-file.

Any thoughts?

PS I don't know if this is relevant but the boxes are written in subfiles that I import into my main .tex using `\input{}`

PPS I defined the boxes in the .cls file like this

```
\newcounter{mybox}[chapter] \setcounter{mybox}{0}
\renewcommand{\themybox}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{mybox}}
\newenvironment{mybox}[2][]{%
\refstepcounter{mybox}%
\ifstrempty{#1}%
{\mdfsetup{%
frametitle={%
\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
\node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=gray!20]
{\strut Box ~\themybox};}}
}%
{\mdfsetup{%
frametitle={%
\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
\node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=gray!20]
{\strut Box ~\themybox:~#1};}}%
}%
\mdfsetup{innertopmargin=10pt,linecolor=gray!20,%
linewidth=2pt,topline=true,%
frametitleaboveskip=\dimexpr-\ht\strutbox\relax
}
\begin{mdframed}[]\relax%
}{\end{mdframed}}
```

PPPS This is what it looks like in text

```
\begin{mybox}[Definitions: Validity]{}
\begin{description}

 \item[Some word]  has this meaning


\end{description}
\end{mybox}
```

And then I tried to use `\input{folder/Boxfile}\label{Box:label1}`

I also tried

```
\begin{mybox}[Definitions: Validity]{}
\begin{description}

 \item[Some word]  has this meaning


\end{description}
\end{mybox}\label{Box:mybox}
```

which also refers to section numbers, not box numbers

Comment: Please give an example of the `mybox` environment in action.

Comment: Basically the `\label` should work since there is a `\refstepcounter`, but it does really matter, where the label is used there.

Comment: Echoing @ChristianHupfer's comment, if I set up an instance of `mybox` via `\begin{mybox}{} \label{box:hello} Hello World. \end{mybox}`, I can easily cross-reference it elsewhere in the document via a `\ref{box:hello}` directive. Incidentally, the `mybox` environment is defined to take 2 arguments (the first being optional), yet the environment does not seem to make any use of the non-optional argument. Is this intentional?

Comment: This is me being sloppy. The second argument used to name "Box" but I hard-coded that and didn't remove the redundant code

Comment: I tried to place an example box in the text and place `\label` directly after \end{mybox} but it still refers to the section number, not the box number

Comment: As Mico said you have to put the `label` command inside your `mybox` environment.

Comment: This must be a clear duplicate...

Comment: For me, the confusing part was that this works `input{folder/filewithtable}\label{tab:nameoftable}` but this does not `input{folder/filewithbox}\label{tab:nameofbox}` where filewithtable contains a table float and filewithbox contains a box

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that the `mybox` environment doesn't float and doesn't feature a `\caption` statement is not crucial for determining whether it can be cross-referenced via LaTeX's `\label`-`\ref` mechanism. What matters is that the environment increments its associated counter via a `\refstepcounter` directive.

The `\label` directive should be provided inside the `mybox` environment, preferably right after the environment is entered.

Aside: Having an environment and a counter both share the exact same name (`mybox`) can easily give rise to confusion. How about calling the counter `myboxcntr` instead?

Please see the following example for how cross-referencing may be performed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{mdframed,tikz}

\newcounter{myboxcntr}[chapter] 
\renewcommand{\themyboxcntr}{\thechapter.\arabic{myboxcntr}}
%\setcounter{myboxcntr}{0} % not needed
\newenvironment{mybox}[2][]{%
   \refstepcounter{myboxcntr}%
   \ifstrempty{#1}%
      {\mdfsetup{%
        frametitle={%
        \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
        \node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=gray!20]%
           {\strut Box \themyboxcntr};}}}%
       {\mdfsetup{%
        frametitle={%
        \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
        \node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=gray!20]%
           {\strut Box \themyboxcntr:~#1};}}}
   \mdfsetup{innertopmargin=10pt,linecolor=gray!20,%
      linewidth=2pt,topline=true,%
      frametitleaboveskip=\dimexpr-\ht\strutbox\relax}
   \begin{mdframed}[]\relax}{%
   \end{mdframed}}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
\crefname{myboxcntr}{Box}{Boxes}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{3} % just for this example

Yawn, big yawn, wakey-wakey, \dots
\begin{mybox}[Greetings!]{}
  \label{box:hello} % <-- crucial: provide a \label statement inside the env.
  Hello World. 
\end{mybox}

A cross-reference to \cref{box:hello}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many environments and their counters have the same name, e.g. `equation`, `table` or `figure` ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - I know. :-) Still, quod licet Iovis (or David Carlisle...), non licet bovis, right?

Comment: Who is bovis then? ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - Pretty much everyone *except* David C. and Enrico G. :-)

Comment: This does work! What is the difference between this and table labels? For tables and figures I use the same structure of creating the table in a seperate file and then using `input{folder/filewithtable}\label{tab:nameoftable}` in my main document which works fine.

Comment: The advantage of my `input{folder/filewithtable}\label{tab:nameoftable} ` solution is that I can use autocomplete in Overleaf that way. But these are minor problems. Thanks :-)

Comment: @Mico: That's idolatrous ;-)